# Why is Amanda Waller not aggressively pursuing the metahumans in The Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

I'm about three seasons into *The Arrow* and about two seasons into *The Flash*. In the second season of *Arrow*, Amanda Waller's reaction to Slade unleashing an army of Mirakuru-enhanced soldiers was to send in a drone to raze the entire city, under the idea that she wanted to entirely root out a source of superpowered criminals. Given *The Flash* seems to have a new superpowered foe nearly every episode, it feels a bit odd that Waller hasn't made similar attempts to eradicate that city. Has this been covered in the show, maybe some case of her realizing that the genie is out of the bottle and that she's better off trying to exploit the metahuman situation rather than trying to eliminate it?

And yes, I realize that this is likely covered in the several seasons I have not watched yet. :) There's a lot of show and I only have so much spare time with the baby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poking around a bit more on the wikis, it sounds like Waller is more proactive with [King Shark](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/King_Shark_(Arrowverse)) from *The Flash*.

> Although Barry and Patty believed him to be dead, King Shark in truth was imprisoned at an A.R.G.U.S. facility on Amanda Waller's orders. Waller wanted to find out if any of King Shark's powers could be weaponized. At the facility, King Shark was kept in a water tank, it's only opening covered by lasers.

That said, I still have not found a reference as to why Waller's response was so extreme to the Mirakuru soldiers. My suspicion is that the villains in The Flash are considered more accidental (although Wells engineered the reactor accident, the occurrence of the villains is more random) while Slade was intentionally creating his own superpowered army, which is more likely to spread.

Comment: All she really cares about is weaponizing metas from what I can tell. It's usually about her.